# Apns is returning 200 to curl request but no push notification sent

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, http2, apple-wallet

I'm sending using this code:

```
curl -v -d "{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"Hello\" } }" -H "apns-topic: <my-pass-identifier>"  --http2 --cert <my-pass-pem-certificate> https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/<my-push-token>
```

to an apple wallet pass I have on my phone. I'm getting this as a response:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.push.apple.com (17.188.162.78) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=api.push.apple.com; OU=management:idms.group.887777; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  start date: Mar 24 17:21:08 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 23 17:21:07 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.push.apple.com" matched cert's "api.push.apple.com"
*  issuer: CN=Apple Public Server RSA CA 12 - G1; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55e534069600)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> POST /3/device/<my-token> HTTP/2
> Host: api.push.apple.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> apns-topic: <my-pass-identifier>
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 33
> 
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 200 
< apns-id: A63D160A-20D0-6880-8B97-5FD0A7923753
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.push.apple.com left intact
```

I think is successful - I'm getting a 200 response and an apns-id, but I'm not getting a push notification or anything on my phone.

Is there anything wrong with this curl request or something else?
Thanks